# Logger in a separate C++ thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging

When logging in a deep loop, are there loggers that allow to generate the log message in the current thread, and then write it to disk from a different thread?

Since writing on disk is the longest operation, this should improve the logger efficiency.

Or could the difference be negligible due to the cache?

Comment: Like Boost.Log's [asynchronous_sink](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/asynchronous_sink.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A logger (or any program, really) that queues the operation for processing by another thread and then returns immediately is called asynchronous. Asynchronous loggers do exist. Here's one that I've used: [g2log](https://bitbucket.org/KjellKod/g2log/src). It's cross platform and been tested on windows and linux.

Whether asynchronous logging has any advantage for you, depends on how much you log stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you logging? Windows? Linux?

If you are using Linux and are working in a very performance sensitive environment you could have a look at [LTTng](https://lttng.org/). There was a [FOSDEM Talk (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIWt4EQlMq8&noredirect=1) about their approach to logging. The essence of it: don't log strings but error codes and arguments to (shared) memory and use a separate process to write the log to disk (shared memory mapped to another process survives a core dump).

Answer (score 1):

Another asynchronous logger is from the POCO library:

http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.AsyncChannel.html